# Best practice to implement classes if every object behaves differently in Java

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

Let's take a real-world example.

Suppose, I have three Dogs, but one dog can differ from the other.
The first dog likes barking and eating, the second dog likes playing and chasing cats and the third dog likes running and jogging (consider these actions as methods).

How do I implement this in Java? What I have to use, what is the best practice? Abstract classes, interfaces or both of them?

Comment: Do they share anything in common?

Comment: @shmosel No, they don't share common methods.

Comment: Then why would you try to fit them into a common type?

Comment: @shmosel Because if we look at this example, each object is a dog, but one differ from the other, that's it. I don't want to create a new class every single time, only dog objects.

Comment: They're not dogs if they share nothing in common.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd implement this as using a single Dog class and composition for `behaviours`

```
public interface Behaviour { void action(); }

public class Bark implements Behaviour {...}
public class ChaseCat implements Behaviour { ... }
public class Eat implements Behaviour {...}
public class Sleep implements Behaviour {...}
... others
public class Dog {

  private List<Behaviour> behaviours;

  public Dog(Behaviour...behaviors) { this.behaviors = Arrays.asList(behaviours); }

  public void play() { 
   // choose random behaviour
   behaviour.action();
  }
}

Dog dog1 = new Dog(new ChaseCat(), new Bark());
Dog dog2 = new Dog(new Eat(), new Sleep());
```

The benefit of this approach is if you expose methods to manage behaviours on the Dog class you can even modify the behaviour as your application is running. For example if a cat scares a dog you can have a method to remove that behaviour for a while and your dog will not do it. Then you can add it later. You get the point.

Comment: good implementation of the [strategy pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/strategy_pattern.htm).

Comment: This kind of approach seems good to me, thank you!

Answer (score -2):

```
// Common interface. i.e. All dogs should be capable of barking!
public interface iDog {
    public void bark();
}

// Common definition. i.e. All dogs bark like this unless specified otherwise
public abstract class Dog implements iDog {
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Woof!");
    }
}

// Concrete Dog 1. Special type of bark, and eats.
public class BarkingEatingDog extends Dog {
    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Big Woof!");
    }

    private void eating() {
        System.out.println("Yum!");
    }
}

// Concrete Dog 2. Plays and chases cats.
public class PlayingCatChasingDog extends Dog {
    public void play() {
        System.out.println("Playing!");
    }

    private void chaseCats() {
        System.out.println("GET OUT OF HERE STUPID CAT!");
    }
}

// Concrete Dog 3. Runs, jogs and barks differently
public class RunningJoggingDog extends Dog {
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Running!");
    }

    private void jog() {
        System.out.println("Jogging!");
    }

    public void bark() {
        System.out.println("Barkety Bark Bark!");
    }
}
```

Comment: What if your dog wants to do ALL of those things and then some. You'll be writing new dog classes forever. What if your dog suddenly doesn't like chasing cats because a cat scared it :) You can't modify its behaviour anymore.

Comment: I don't want to create a new class every single time when I want to create a dog object